# EParseError wamp: The configuration files contains syntax error on line 592. Unknown parameter name "type"

Tags: php, wampserver

I tried to update php version from 7 to 8.1 through add on in wamp 3.2.5. Also Edited the path in the environment variable. But I'm facing this issue when I run the wamp server a pop up is displayed with the above error.

Answer (score 0):

You require WAMPServer 3.2.6 to run PHP8.1.

You can get the upgrade from [The Backup repo here](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en). its easier to find on there than SourceForge, but it is available there also if you prefer.

[Direct link to the WAMPServer 3.2.6 upgrade](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/updates/wampserver3_x86_x64_update3.2.6.exe)

This upgrade will not make any changes to Apache/MySQL/mariaDB/PHP or anything other than the WAMPServer internals. It is a cumulative update and therefore can be run on any version of WAMPServer greater than or equal to 3.0.1.

```
---Changelog Wampserver 3.2.6
Support for PHP 8.1
Improve default_file for MySQL and MariaDB service
Support of Apache Graceful Restart
Restart Wampserver in one click
Display date/time of last startup
Apache configurations comparison
Ability to update Apache configuration when changing version: LoadModule - Include - Listen port - httpd-vhosts.conf - httpd-ssl.conf
openssl.cnf - apache2.4.xx\conf\Certs\ folder if existing
Ability to restore httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf saved when installing an Apache version
Improved display of command windows
Ability to check for updates to Wampserver, Aestan Tray Menu, Apache, PHP, MySQL, MariaDB, etc.
```